# Conceptual: incrementing inside a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, auto-increment

**The scenario**

I am working on a HUD class to aid me in development of an OpenGL project. I want to be able to add new elements onto the screen dynamically (positioning will happen automatically) with the use of an `add_element(char*, float)` method. Here is the said code:

```
class HUD {
public:
    HUD();
    ~HUD();
private:
    int elements,
        spacing;
public:
    void add_element(char*, float);
};

HUD::HUD() : elements(0), spacing(10) {}
HUD::~HUD() {}

void HUD::add_element(char* string, float value) {

    ++elements;
    // .. render to screen .. //
}
```

The basic idea is: It will position them vertically for me as I continue to add elements.

**The problem**

The class gets instantiated inside the main function, and the elements get added and drawn to the screen within and at the end of my game loop. This means, every frame, the `element` counter gets incremented, when it should only increment the first time a unique element is added. I have thought about adding unique identifiers as an argument, like numbering them manually every time I call the method, but this seems to defeat the purpose I am going for.

I am just looking for some ideas that can solve this type of incrementing inside a loop. I have a few scenarios in which I need to do this, and the HUD is the first one I ran into.

Comment: Split it up in two functions? add_element and render_elements?

Comment: I don't see how this would make any difference, as the incrementing still gets called every frame. Maybe show an example?

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the problem is that you're trying to solve.  Can you clarify?

Comment: My idea was that the add_element function only gets called when you add an element, and render_elements gets called every frame. I guess I didn't completely understand what you're doing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a similar thing working on an XNA game (so C#). My class had a list of things to be written on screen:

```
struct to_write {
    string text;
    Vector2 position;    // X and Y coords relative to the screen
}

private List<to_write> _logs;
```

I did a "write" function which adds a new to_write element to the _logs list

```
void Write(string txt, Vector2 pos)
{
    _logs.AddLast(new to_Write() { text = txt, position = pos });
}
```

but the actual output on screen happened only during the draw function:

```
foreach(to_write w in _logs)
    // write w.text at coordinates w.position.x and w.position.y

_logs.Clear();
```

This class's Update() and Draw() methods were the last that were called allowing every other component to add its own informations to the HUD. You can make things simpler by using a simple array and keeping an array pointer, this way both adding element to write and clearing the list are O(1).

Comment: I like this. So basically every frame, before I draw, I am building a list of elements to use in the HUD, and then clearing it at the end of the loop. Thanks!

Comment: Question though. <list> seems to be part of the C++ stl, but is the version you are using, List, C# specific?

Comment: List is C#, you'll probably want to use std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

Later on these "elements" you write about, will be an instance of a class ( that's just the nice way to do it ), lets say: Element. Then you could add a private member for the HUD class as `std::set<Element>elements` , witch is a container that couldn't have the same object twice. So in your add_element method you add `elements.insert( element )` with the method `elements.size()` you will get the unique element count in it.

Btw, this isn't efficient ( trying to insert the elements in every frame ) but you get the picture.
[See c++ doc about std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)

Comment: So, I could add the char name (which should always be unique) into the set, and it would only be able to add it if it was unique? aka the first time it is called?

Comment: well yeah, if its unique then it will work just as fine as a class. Btw try to avoid char* if possible because of the issues with the \0 string closer character. Use instead std::string. It has all the methods u'll need. So at the end you will have an std::set<std::string> elements container.